# Troubleshooting joining a group in Mint in VirtualBox

Tags: group

I am trying to join my user to the `vboxsf` group to access a VirtualBox shared folder from inside my Linux Mint virtual machine. However I'm encountering a problem that I can't troubleshoot.

I've edited `/etc/groups` to add my user to the appropriate group.

```
user394-VirtualBox media # grep user394 /etc/group
...
vboxsf:x:108:user394
```

But I can't access a directory that that group supposedly has permissions to:

```
user394@user394-VirtualBox /media $ cd sf_Dropbox/
bash: cd: sf_Dropbox/: Permission denied

user394@user394-VirtualBox /media $ ls -lha
total 40K
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   4.0K Jul 13 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root   4.0K Mar 16 22:04 ..
drwxrwx---   1 root vboxsf  28K Jul 13 12:08 sf_Dropbox
drwxrwx---   1 root vboxsf    0 Jul 13 12:16 sf_mint-shared-folder
```

The command `groups` shows that I'm not a member, yet `groups {user}` and `id` seem to indicate that I am:

```
user394@user394-VirtualBox /media $ groups
user394 adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare
user394@user394-VirtualBox /media $ id
uid=1000(user394) gid=1000(user394) groups=1000(user394),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),33(www-data),46(plugdev),112(lpadmin),118(sambashare)
user394@user394-VirtualBox /media $ groups user394
user394 : user394 adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev vboxsf lpadmin sambashare
```

How can I properly join this group and access these directories?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I logged out of and back into my terminal sessions, but that did no good. What I needed to do was log out of my *GUI* session. Once I did that, I had the group memberships I was expecting.